# HTTP - How to update a user on a long running process

Tags: php, http

So today I was maintaining some old code and I came across a method of updating the UI for a long running process that I was not familiar with.

Basically an importer processes many thousands for rows of CSV data and (in PHP) echoes out markup at each stage.
The markup itself was being displayed within an iframe enclosed in a regular page.

Is this method viable / reliable or is that a better way to handle such situations?

It feels kinda wrong to have a HTTP Request that remains open for the sole purpose of slowly returning html (progress information).
But is there a better way?

(the code I was maintaining was PHP but I guess thats besides the point)

Comment: i wouldn't do it, for ling running processes , i would just email the user when done.

Answer (score 0):

IF you need you can try doing i.e. `printf("done %d of %d", $done, $toDo); flush();` and no frame is needed. The key is `flush();`